# Can Apache Zeppelin auto-close its SparkContext after some time and re-open it?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I set up a simple Spark cluster in standalone mode and want to use Apache Zeppelin as an interactive Spark "scratchpad". Unfortunately, when the `SparkContext` is started, it occupies all cores on my experimenting cluster. I know there is a new feature called "Dynamic Allocation" but it works only with YARN. I do not have YARN on this cluster and I do not want to run a full-fledged Hadoop stack because I want to use Cassandra as the data backend.

Is this somehow possible without using YARN?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mesos rather than Yarn. Spark allows you to set the number of cores it requests from Mesos in coarse-grained mode. To do that, set the following options:

```
spark.mesos.coarse=true 
spark.cores.max={The number of cores you wish to allocate}
```

You can set these via the Interpreter window in Zeppelin.

Note that in-coarse grained mode, Zeppelin will occupy these cores persistently - even when it's not actually doing any work.

Comment: I actually went with YARN in the end. This has the advantage that I also have HDFS where I can upload the data to be added to Cassandra. I then can define my custom `InputFormat`s, use `sc.newAPIHadoopFile` to get RDDs and add them to the database in Spark.

Answer (score 0):

I actually went with YARN in the end, because I figured out having a Hadoop stack underneath has some additional advantages:

- I can use HDFS as a source for the data to import into Cassandra so I don't have to worry about accessibility of the source files from Spark
- I can write custom `InputFormat`s to read the data, do pre-processing with Spark and spill the results to Cassandra

I think doing the pre-processing on the Cluster should be faster than on the client.